# how to submit a web form with ".do" action using python?

Tags: python, html

I know how to submit a form using python, but I can not do when the form action is .do example: I want to submit to hotels.com but its form is 'form class="cont-bd" action="/search.do" role="search"'
 I cannot submit it using
        urllib.request.urlopen (url,data)
Any help is really appreciated.

```
url="http://www.hotels.com/search.do"
value={'q-destination':'los angles'}
data=urllib.parse.urlencode(value)
data=data.encode('utf-8')
urllink = urllib.request.urlopen(url,data)
soup=BeautifulSoup(urllink,"html.parser")
figurs=soup.findAll("img",class_="u-photo")    
print(figurs)
```

Comment: Actually you shouldn't care about the `action` attribute, it's the same for you (the client) who receives the sent values. The [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/) package will be useful here.

Comment: Thanks cdonts, but I could submit a form into other website,let say "quikbook" with the same exact code but could not submit into hotels.com so I assumed there might be a problem with the .do action of the form

Comment: There's no "do" action, just a file named `search.do` which is receiving the user input. It would be easier to us to help you if we could see your code! :)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code!

Comment: @cdonts Actually I figured out the problem. It is the problem of entering the city name and state e.g los Angles,CA. Thanks for your help